# How to return average of one group-by column out of multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe that looks like:

```
Type  Time  Node  Bytes
 A     1     0     11         
 A     1     0     12
 B     1     0     13
 B     1     1     14
```

I want to group by dataframe by type, time and node and mean the data based  on Type. The resultant  dataframe should  look like:

```
 Mean_A     Mean_B
  11.5      13.5
```

Being a beginner in pandas dataframe, I have written a code that simply does group by and mean.

```
total_kilobytes = data.groupby(['Time','Node','Type'])['KilobytesRaw'].sum().mean().
```

This returns mean of all types , but I want individual mean for each type and store result as a dataframe and not a series.

Comment: If your question was answered, please accept the most helpful answer by clicking the grey check to the left of that answer to toggle it green. It helps the community. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you need:

```
total_kilobytes = data.groupby('Type')['Bytes'].mean().to_frame().T.add_prefix('Mean_')
print (total_kilobytes)
Type   Mean_A  Mean_B
Bytes    11.5    13.5
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [`pd.pivot_table`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.pivot_table.html):

```
res = pd.pivot_table(df, columns='Type', values=['Bytes']).add_prefix('Mean_')

print(res)

Type   Mean_A  Mean_B
Bytes    11.5    13.5
```